# Dealing with questions that get Community-bumped a lot

Tags: discussion

Since May 2016, data about when Community bumps a question to the front page [has been available in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260010/). This gives us a way to automatically identify questions that get kicked to the front page frequently. Specifically, [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/539033/community-bumped-posts-in-need-of-attention?MinimumBumpCount=2) captures a notion of questions that get bumped often. I feel these posts deserve our attention if for no other reason than that it gets boring seeing them on the front page every month. (For reference, [here are the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/) for determining which posts get bumped. Since our site is small, and we have considerably fewer than 30 * 24 = 720 bumpable questions, every bumpable question gets bumped every month.)

Here are the posts from the query that have 5 recorded bumps (i.e. monthly since May):

- [Song played at the end of episode 20 of Parasyte](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/31323/)
- [How do the visions happen when Itami hits his head on EP.1?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/31342/)
- [Who is Mir's Mind Guardian?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29582/)
- [What does Headphone Actor represent or mean?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9942/)
- [In the end of the last episode of RahXephon, does everyone retain their old memories?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3755/)
- [What happened to Retsu's doll at the clothing shop?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4606/)
- [Ending of Bloody Monday season 3](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5691/)
- [Why didn't Masashi Miyamoto take Taira's chip after cutting his fingers?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6751/)

For each of these posts, we should consider the following approaches to get the post off the list of bumpable questions:

- Is the question off-topic? If so, we should close it.
- Is the question bad? If so, we should downvote it.
- Are the existing answers to the question good? If so, we should upvote them.
- Are the existing answers to the question unsalvageably bad? If so, we should downvote them, and flag them as low-quality and/or vote to delete them.
- Are the existing answers to the question acceptable, but not *good*? If so, we should write a better answer, or bounty the question to encourage somebody to write a better answer.

For example, on the Parasyte question (which is the only one of these that I know enough about), I investigated a little bit and found that the existing answer was correct - so I upvoted it. Now, this question won't get bumped anymore!

I encourage you all to do the same.

Comment: in regards to the question on Mir's Mind Guardian i was waiting on a reference as i have been unable to find a fan translated version of the game to verify it but your comment does make sense so i have accepted it